HashCode & Equals --> Hibernate + Collections
Какой ваш подход? Добавляете ли вы в переопределение hashcode & equals - колекции дочерних сущностей с @ManyToOne / @OneToMany ? При использовании Hibernate. Если да - то почему? если нет - то почему?
Какой подход лучше?

Не совсем понятно, какая связь между коллекциями, отношениями и методами equals() и hashCode(), но при работе с БД их можно переопределять как сравнение айдишников и возврат какого-нибудь числа (например, getClass().hashCode()) соответственно. Об этом можно почитать в статье от Vlad Mihalcea.
